# TypeScript: Infer type of nested union type

Tags: typescript

I'm using objects in TypeScript that can potentially contain a lazy link where the data can be fetched or the data itself. That's why these properties get a union type T | string.

Now I want to write a type safe resolve function to resolve nested properties that returns the nested type.

```
type TypeOrString<T> = T | string;


interface A {
    propA: TypeOrString<B>;
}

interface B {
    propB: TypeOrString<any[]>;
}


function resolve<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>
(data: T | string, p1: K1, p2: K2): T[K1][K2] {
    return null;
}

let a:A;
let b:TypeOrString<any[]> = resolve(a, "propA", "propB");

//Error TS2345: Argument of type '"propB"' is not assignable 
//to parameter of type '"toString" | "valueOf"'.
```

But the compiler gives me an error, TS2345: Argument of type '"propB"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"toString" | "valueOf"'. Is there any chance to infer the type of propB from an instance of interface A?

Answer (score 4):

You can get kind of what you're looking for by using [recursive mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114#issuecomment-259776847) to model the fact that not only is something "data or a string", but that the data is itself "data or a string".  Like this:

```
type DeepTypeOrString<T> = string | {
  [K in keyof T]: DeepTypeOrString<T[K]>
}
```

This mostly gives you what you want for primitives and plain object types.  Arrays are another story, but that will be cleared up once the [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) feature lands in TypeScript 2.8.

Now let's define `A` and `B` by the actual data you expect them to be as opposed to the "maybe string" version:

```
interface A  {
  propA: B
}
interface B {
  propB: any[]
}
```

And your `resolve()` function is similar to before, except that `data` is declared to be of type `DeepTypeOrString<T>`:

```
declare function resolve<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>(
  data: DeepTypeOrString<T>, p1: K1, p2: K2
): T[K1][K2];
```

Now when you call `resolve()`, you will see the inference you expect:

```
declare const a: DeepTypeOrString<A>;
const ret = resolve(a, 'propA', 'propB') // ret is inferred as any[]
```

Hope that helps; good luck!